# Key clicks behave different on different browsers, why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I want to scroll up and down to certain sections on my website and loop around. I use this .js code and it works perfectly fine with Safari, but for some reason Chrome doesn't recognise ArrowUp and ArrowDown at all.

```
let currentPiece = "p1";
const pieces = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5"];

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  let key = e.key;
  if (key == "ArrowUp" || key == "w" || key == "W") {
    const currentIndex = pieces.indexOf(currentPiece);
    currentPiece = currentIndex === 0 ? pieces[pieces.length - 1] : pieces[currentIndex -1];
    document.getElementById(currentPiece).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  } else if (key == "ArrowDown" || key == "s" || key == "S") {
    const currentIndex = pieces.indexOf(currentPiece);
    currentPiece = currentIndex === pieces.length - 1 ? pieces[0] : pieces[currentIndex +1];
    document.getElementById(currentPiece).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
}
```

I previously used keycodes but stopped since they are outdated(?) and Chrome still had some weird problems not looping around when using arrow keys and going to the wrong spot sometimes for no apparent reason...

Comment: Check `e.code` instead of `e.key`